# Connect Sqlite using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I need the fix the problem when I put all information and click save there's nothing on the database

**Error:**

**E/flutter (12919): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(table PERSON has no column named salary (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): ,**

[image]

db_helper.dart:

```
import 'package:sqlite_demo/litedb.dart';
import 'package:sqlite_demo/models/person.dart';

class DbHelper extends LiteDb {

  getAllPersons() async {
    List<Person> persons = [];
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
    List<Map> myMap = await inquiry(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < myMap.length; i ++) {
      persons.add(Person.fromMap(myMap[i]));
    }
    return persons;
  }

  insertNewPerson(Person person) async {
    String sql = '''
       INSERT INTO PERSON(name, age, salary)
       VALUES ( '${person.name}' , ${person.age} , ${person.salary})
    ''';
    int result = await insert(sql);
    return result;
  }

  updatePerson(Person person) async {
    String sql = '''
       UPDATE PERSON SET 
       name = '${person.name}',
       age = ${person.age},
       salary = ${person.salary}
       WHERE 
       id = ${person.id}
    ''';
    int result = await update(sql);
    return result;
  }

  deletePerson(Person person) async {
    String sql = '''
       DELETE FROM PERSON
       WHERE 
       id = ${person.id}
    ''';
    int result = await update(sql);
    return result;
  }
}
```

litedb.dart:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class LiteDb {

  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database?> get getInstance async {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = await instance();
      return _db;
    } else {
      return _db;
    }
  }

  instance() async {
    // Get a location using getDatabasesPath
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'lite_sql.db');

    // open the database
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 2,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
          // When creating the db, create the table
          await db.execute(
              '''  
                CREATE TABLE PERSON (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, age INTEGER);
                CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PERSON_ID INTEGER NOT  NULL, ACCOUNT INTEGER NOT NULL, VALUE REAL);
              ''');
          print('Text Database has been created');
        },
        onUpgrade: (Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async {
          if (newVersion >= 2) {
            await db.execute('''
            ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD COLUMN salary REAL NULL
            ''');
          }
        }
    );
    print(' Database connected');
    return database;
  }

  inquiry(String sqlTxt) async {
    Database? db = await getInstance;
    // Get the records
    List<Map> list = await db!.rawQuery(sqlTxt);
    return list;
  }

  insert(String sqlTxt) async {
    Database? db = await getInstance;
    // Insert some record
    int count = await db!.rawInsert(sqlTxt);
    return count;
  }

  update(String sqlTxt) async {
    Database? db = await getInstance;
    // Update some record
    int count = await db!.rawUpdate(sqlTxt);
    return count;
  }

  delete(String sqlTxt) async {
    Database? db = await getInstance;
    // Delete some record
    int count = await db!.rawDelete(sqlTxt);
    return count;
  }
}
```

person.dart:

```
class Person {

  int id;
  String name;
  int age;
  double salary;

  Person({required this.id, required this.name, required this.age, this.salary = 0.0});

  factory Person.getNewEmpty() {
    return Person(
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        age: 0
    );
  }

  factory Person.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return Person(
        id: map['id'] ?? 0,
        name: map['name'] ?? '',
        age: map['age'] ?? 0,
        salary: map['salary']?.toDouble() ?? 0.0
    );
  }
}
```

person_details.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqlite_demo/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:sqlite_demo/models/person.dart';

class PersonDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonDetails({Key? key, required this.person}) : super(key: key);

  final Person person;

  @override
  State<PersonDetails> createState() => _PersonDetailsState();
}

class _PersonDetailsState extends State<PersonDetails> {
  DbHelper helper = DbHelper();

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController salaryController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    nameController.text = widget.person.name;
    ageController.text = widget.person.age.toString();
    salaryController.text = widget.person.salary.toString();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.person.name),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            moveToLastScreen();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0, left: 15.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Title',
                    icon: Icon(Icons.title),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0, left: 15.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: ageController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'age',
                    icon: Icon(Icons.apps_outage_outlined),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0, left: 15.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: salaryController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'salary',
                    icon: Icon(Icons.apps_outage_outlined),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Fourth Element
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
                        ) ,
                        child: const Text( 'Save',textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Person person = widget.person;
                          person.name = nameController.text;
                          person.age = int.parse(ageController.text);
                          person.salary = double.parse(salaryController.text);
                          _saveData(person);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 5.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
                        ) ,
                        child: const Text( 'Delete',textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _deleteData(widget.person);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _saveData(Person person) async {
    if (person.id == 0) {
      await helper.insertNewPerson(person);
    } else {
      await helper.updatePerson(person);
    }
    moveToLastScreen();
  }

  _deleteData(Person person) async {
    if (person.id > 0) {
      await helper.deletePerson(person);
    }
    moveToLastScreen();
  }

  void moveToLastScreen(){
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
  }

  void _showAlertDialog(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog alertDialog = AlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(message),
    );
    showDialog(context:context, builder:(_) => alertDialog);
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to update column(`salary `)/db?

Comment: check my code because I did not understand

Comment: **salary** column not exits, try inside onCreate ...**salary* table

Comment: Can you write the code solution please

Comment: try to uninstall the app